# Problems with connect in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyqt5

I have a problem. I am writing a simple app in Pyqt5. I am trying to do this block of code in PyQt:

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
QEventLoop event;
connect(response,SIGNAL(finished()),&event,SLOT(quit()));
event.exec();
QString html = response->readAll();
```

But when I am trying to use "connect" IDE tells me that "MainWindow" don't have method. How can I do it ?? Please help

This is my code:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        # window settings
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello world app")

        # main layout
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        # main widgets
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Enter URL:")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.label_conn = QtWidgets.QLabel("")
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Connect")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_click)

        # adding widgets to layout
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.line)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label_conn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

        self.connect()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `connect` method belongs to the *signal* that you wish to connect to a specific *slot*, not to the `MainWindow` widget itself. (BTW, you should consider inheriting from `QMainWindow` instead.)

In your code, the `MainWindow` widget is not a signal, so does not have a `connect` method. Also, even if it did, you need to specify the slot to which you're trying to connect the signal, which is also missing.

In other words, you must declare a `pyqtSignal`, if you're not using a pre-existing one, and then `connect` it to the `pyqtSlot` of your choice. Whether this slot is pre-defined or a custom one is up to you.

Consider the following code snippet, which I tested in Python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -B

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QPushButton

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)

    diag = QDialog()
    diag.setWindowTitle('Signal Demo')
    diag.resize(200,50)

    btn  = QPushButton(diag)
    btn.setText('Close Dialog')

    # connect button's clicked signal to dialog's close slot
    btn.clicked.connect(diag.close)

    diag.show()
    diag.exec_()
```

Notice that the button's `clicked` signal, not the button, is what gets `connect`ed to the dialog's `close` slot, not the dialog itself.

---

#### EDIT 1:

Just noticed that the very code you've posted has an example of how to properly perform a connection.

If your code has not simply been copy-pasted from some other place, you should've noticed that you seem to know how to properly connect signals and slots already. This line plainly gives it away:

```
self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_click)
```

If your `MainWindow` does have a `btn_click` method, then it should get invoked after the `QPushButton` named `btn` gets `clicked`.

---

#### EDIT 2:

Based on your recent comment, you seem to simply be trying to translate a snippet for a larger application, so consider the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest, QNetworkReply
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEventLoop, QUrl

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)))
event = QEventLoop()
response.finished.connect(event.quit)
event.exec()
html = str(response.readAll())   # in Python3 all strings are unicode, so QString is not defined
print(html)
```

The code above was tested to work as expected.

**PS:** I did notice that some seemingly valid URLs were returning an empty response (e.g. `http://sourceforge.net/`), but others, such as the one above, worked fine. It seems to be unrelated to the code snippet itself.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't understand how can I do this:

QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
QEventLoop event;
connect(response,SIGNAL(finished()),&event,SLOT(quit()));
event.exec();
QString html = response->readAll();

Comment: This seems different from the original post on the `MainWindow` not having a `connect` method. You can't just take C++ code and move it into Python and expect it to work without modification, if that's that you're doing. Have you looked at the [PyQt5 Docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/)?

Comment: @OlegKlimenko: I've updated the post based on my understanding of your previous comment.

Comment: yes, this is what I need, thanks, but it returned an empty string.

Comment: @OlegKlimenko. The code in Edit2 works fine for me - all you need to do is create a `QApplication` and provide a valid url. The returned `html` will be a `QByteArray` (not a string).

Comment: @OlegKlimenko: Made some minor edits to the code to account for the `QApplication` and the `QByteArray` conversion to a `str` type.

Comment: @ray I've tried to convert to str, using QByteArray.data() It must return str, and tried to check the length. I've had zero.

Comment: I've entered the url, which is working, but returning zero. I've tried on another and it works

Comment: @OlegKlimenko: I observed the same behavior. I've updated the code to something that was tested to work.